# Concatenate strings from multiple columns and multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to concatenate the strings from multiple rows and multiple columns in SQL Server.

My table is like this:

```
     ItemId         AttributeName      AttributeValue
    ----------      -------------      --------------
    1               Website            www.abc.com
    1               Github             github.com/abc
    1               Facebook           facebook.com/abc
    2               Website            www.123.com
    2               Instagram          instagram.com/123
```

and the desired output is:

```
     ItemId         Weblinks      
    ----------      -------------      
    1               Website: www.abc.com; Github: github.com/abc; Facebook: facebook.com/abc    
    2               Website: www.123.com; Instagram: instagram.com/123
```

I read from other similar questions that XML PATH is probably required. Please could anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Does the order of the sites matter?

Comment: Whith version? SQL Server 2017 added the `STRING_AGG` function, which means that function is now available in the two out of the three mainstream versions (SQL Server 2014 is already out of mainstream support)

Comment: Hi @urban, nope the order of the sites doesn't matter.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't be using an Attrribute/Value schema in the first place. It's almost as bad as stuffing everything in a single cell - querying becomes a lot harder, indexing almost useless, you lose all integrity constraints and actually have to store everything using a single inappropriate type. Which adds conversion problems. Even if you used separate columns per type, you'd still get no usable indexing or integrity constraints.

Comment: If you don't really want to use individual attributes in queries, a very good option (very strong hint here) would be to store the data as XML or even better JSON - which, btw looks a lot like your desired result. You could use persisted computed columns with XPath/JsonPath expressions to extract any attributes needed for querying and indexing. XML is supported since 2005, JSON since 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done with a 2 step query:

```
SELECT t.id, STRING_AGG(t.sites, ' ') as Weblinks
FROM (
  SELECT id, CONCAT(attrName, ': ', attrValue, ';') as sites
  FROM test
) as t
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

The inner concatenates attribute value and name in the desired format, while the outer aggregates the results per user id. Coming from MySQL I find that simpler for some reason.

Demo: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99fd8e50f3ecfa4fbf99236836a38df9)

UPDATE: based on @Panagiotis comment

```
SELECT t.id, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(t.attrName, ': ', t.attrValue, ';'), ' ') as Weblinks
FROM test t
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Demo 2: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ecf708399cb9cf24691dc81bc8f2ff9)

Comment: There's no need for two steps

Comment: True, one could add concat in string_agg, thats what you are saying right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I'm still on SQL Server 2014 so I can't use the `STRING_AGG` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR XML PATH()` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.ItemId, STUFF(Weblinks, 1, 1, '') AS Weblinks      
FROM table T CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT CONCAT(';', T1.AttributeName, ':', T1.AttributeValue)
       FROM table T1 
       WHERE T1.ITEMID = T.ITEMID
       FOR XML PATH('')
     ) T1(Weblinks);
```